# Как прочитать настройки телефона XIAOMI программно?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

При установке приложения на телефонах XIAOMI 9T выставляются следующие права по умолчанию (для приложения):

1. Контроль активности: "Умный режим";
2. Другие разрешения:
   a. Экран блокировки - выключен,
   b. Отображать всплывающие окна, когда запущено в фоновом режиме - выключен

Я перечислил только те настройки, которые хотел бы поменять.

Из приложения я могу вызвать настройки прав при помощи кода:

```
procedure TfmMain.GetAddControl;
 Var Intent : JIntent;
     CN : JComponentName;
begin
 CN := TJComponentName.JavaClass.init(StringToJString('com.miui.securitycenter'), StringToJString('com.miui.appmanager.ApplicationsDetailsActivity'));
 if CN <> Nil then
 Begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setComponent(CN);
  Intent.PutExtra(StringToJString('package_name') , StringToJString('com.embarcadero.' + ProgramName));
  Intent.PutExtra(StringToJString('package_label'), StringToJString(ProgramName));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
 End;
end;
```

Как мне объяснили, поменять программно я их не смогу - только показать.

Хотелось бы программно прочитать настройки, чтоб не всегда вызывать окно настроек прав, а только, когда они неверные.
Возможно ли такое?